# how to create several variables with a loop from a "character variable"?

Tags: loops, merge

I have a dataframe with medicine names (character) that has been prescribed every day
So I need to count how many times has been prescribed those medicines
My data frame is named "recipe" and it has "date", "medicine" and other variables

I have this script:

`losart <- recipe %>%  filter(year==2019) %>% filter(medicine=="losartan") %>%  count(date) %>% rename("losartan" = "n")`

then it changes to (for the next medicine):

`atorvast <- recipe %>%  filter(year==2019) %>% filter(medicine=="atorvastatina") %>%  count(date) %>% rename("atorvast" = "n")`

for the next medicine name.
Then I merged every dataframe by date
But I have too many medicines, so I would like to create every dataframe with a loop